# How to serialize Tensorflow Serving request to reduce inference/predict latency?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I have exported a TF SavedModel from an Estimator using TensorServingInputReceiver as follows:

```
def serving_input_fn():
    input_ph = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 3, 224, 224], name = 'image_batches')
    input_tensors = input_ph
    return tf.estimator.export.TensorServingInputReceiver(input_tensors, input_ph)
```

and export the SavedModel as follows:

```
warm_start = tf.estimator.WarmStartSettings(CKPT_DIR)
    classifier = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn = model_fn, warm_start_from = warm_start)
    classifier.export_savedmodel(export_dir_base = SAVED_MODEL_DIR, serving_input_receiver_fn = serving_input_fn)
```

However, when I use this SavedModel to perform predictions in Tensorflow Serving:

```
json_dict = {'signature_name': 'serving_default', 'instances': data}
```

where data is a numpy array, I obtain speed of only about 1/5 to 1/6 of local direct inference using the SavedModel.

Currently I'm thinking the problem may be the serialization part of the request in JSON as suggested [here](https://medium.com/@avidaneran/tensorflow-serving-rest-vs-grpc-e8cef9d4ff62). So does anyone know how to perform serialization of the request before sending, or have any suggestions as to why the inference speed using TF Serving is much slower than direct inference?

Answer (score 1):

I have been facing the same situation, jason.dumps causes 90% of delay, if the image size is reduced to say (1,100,100,3) the inference speed increases by 3 fold, so basically json.dumps file is too large and thus consuming more time to write and read from memory. I tried ultrajson i.e ujson but there wasn't any observable improvement.

```
trs = img1.tolist()
data = json.dumps({"signature_name": "serving_default", "instances": trs})
```

As my model architecture requires INT I don't see any other option to serialize the data.

Modifying the input architecture can shift our input requirement of UINT to STRING which can be done by

```
dl_request = requests.get(IMAGE, stream=True)
jpeg_bytes = base64.b64encode(dl_request.content).decode('utf-8')
predict_request = '{"instances" : [{"b64": "%s"}]}' % jpeg_bytes
response = requests.post(SERVER_URL, data=predict_request)
```

This fetches good results , but how to convert model input type from INT to STRING?

Any suggestions??

Comment: I have also observed some speedups using String; however, the delay caused by json.dumps of [batch_size, 224, 224, 3] image file in my case is still very large. Regarding converting your model input type from Int to String, maybe you can design your input function to accept String inputs, and use something like Estimator input function to convert String to Int?

Answer (score 0):

I have been facing the same situation, jason.dumps causes 90% of delay, if the image size is reduced to say (1,100,100,3) the inference speed increases by 3 fold, so basically json.dumps file is too large and thus consuming more time to write and read from memory. I tried ultrajson i.e ujson but there wasn't any observable improvement.

```
trs = img1.tolist()
data = json.dumps({"signature_name": "serving_default", "instances": trs})
```

As my model architecture requires INT I don't see any other option to serialize the data.

Any suggestions??